The space of square-integrable functions is a Hilbert space
I was reading about the space of square-integrable functions, and need some clarification on whether my understanding is correct regarding the fact that it is also a Hilbert space.
The space of square-integrable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ form the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C})$. Any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C})$ satisfies
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathrm{d}x\;f^*(x)f(x)<\infty. $$
I read that $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C})$ is somewhat equivalent (in what sense?) to (infinite dimensional) Euclidean 2 space $\ell^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C})$, which is complete under the Euclidean 2-norm $|| \cdot ||_2$, since every $\ell^p$ space is complete under its respective norm. Also, although $\ell^p$ in general do not have an inner product structure, $\ell^2$ happens to be compatible with an inner product, which we write as $\langle \,.,.\rangle_2$. Define the inner product as follows:
$$ \langle f,g \rangle_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathrm{d}x\;f^*(x)g(x). $$
Thus, $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C})$ is complete under the 2-norm, and has an inner product as defined above, therefore it is a Hilbert space.

Are you sure what you're talking about? I know that $L^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C})$ with the counting measure is $l^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C})$. Regardless, you can demonstrate that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space directly, verify that $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_2$ is a inner product, consider the norm $|\cdot|_2 = \sqrt{\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_2}$ and show that L^2 is complete with this norm.

$L^2$ is not simply the set of all square-integrable functions. $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1&x = 0\0&x\ne 0\end{cases}$$ is an example of such a function for which $|f|_2^2 = \langle f,f\rangle_2 = 0$ even though $f \not\equiv 0$. $L^2$ is the set of equivalence classes of such functions where $f \sim g$ if $|f - g|_2 = 0$.

As for how $L^2$ and $\ell^2$ are equivalent, they are both infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces with countable Schauder bases. Since the bases are both in bijection with the natural numbers, they are in bijection with each other. That bijection induces an isomorphism of the spaces. However, this argument relies on $L^2$ being complete, so you should not rely on this isomorphism to show that $L^2$ is complete.

@PaulSinclair The Wikipedia page on square-integrable function says: "The vector space of (equivalence classes of) square integrable functions (with respect to Lebesgue measure) forms the $L^p$ space with $p=2$." Is this simply wrong, or somewhat equivalent to your first comment? Also, I do not get the last sentence of your second comment, is one of the $L^2$'s supposed to be $\ell^2$? Thanks.

For your first point. It says right there "equivalence classes". of functions. Not functions, but equivalence classes of functions. That is exactly what I pointed out. For the second point, no. I am saying that the argument that $L^2$ and $\ell^2$ are isomorphic requires them to be complete. So you cannot use that isomorphism to claim that $L^2$ is complete. Without completeness of $L^2$, the most you can claim as I described is that $L^2$ is isomorphic to some subspace of $\ell^2$. So you have to prove $L^2$ is complete some other way to say that it is isomorphic to $\ell^2$.
